# JBoss validator cannot resolve arrays?

Tags: jsf, jboss

Please, have a look at the following line in my .xhtml file that uses Java Server Faces:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="cb1"
  value="#{DvdStreamSelectBean.ids[node.identifier]}"
  title="#{node.identifier}"
  valueChangeListener="#{DvdStreamSelectBean.setNodeState}"
  onclick="switchSubNodes(this);"/>
<h:outputText value="#{node.description}" styleClass="text"/>
```

Especially this part:

```
value="#{DvdStreamSelectBean.ids[node.identifier]}"
```

That's where error is reported:

> DvdStreamSelectBean cannot be resolved.

At every other place DvdStreamSelectBean is resolved ok, however, only at this place it is "not resolved". Is it because it referencing array? What confuses it?

Here is what "ids" is:

```
private HashMap<String, Boolean> ids = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

And here is what "node" is:

```
protected TreeNodeChecked treeData;
```

I'm using JBoss tools in Eclipse Indigo+Java Server Faces 2.x.

Comment: Shouldn't it start with lower case as per naming conventions? Or have you forced an uppercased name? Further, does this problem only occur in form of an IDE validation error, or does this problem also occur when you really run the code? You namely sound like that you've not really executed the code and are trusting the IDE a bit too much.

Comment: Right. I am upset with IDE marking the error. The code I didn't run yet because I am having other problems with it, but I am somehow sure this is IDE only error which I wanted to resolve anyway.

Comment: If the code runs, then it's a bug in the JBoss Tools plugin (I assume that the IDE is delegating EL validation to it). How exactly is the bean been registered? JSF `@ManagedBean` or CDI `@Named`? Have you tried following the naming conventions? (instance variable names should start with lowercase)

Comment: It's ManagedBean. Which variable should I start lowercase?

Comment: To comply naming conventions, the `#{DvdStreamSelectBean}` should be `#{dvdStreamSelectBean}`.

Comment: Note that this is already the default managed bean name for a `@ManagedBean` on a `public class DvdStreamSelectBean {}` without explicitly specifying the `name` attribute on the `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: Yes, I understand there is default bean name. I am using `@ManagedBean DvdStreamSelectBean @Name "DvdStreamSelectBean"`.

Comment: Sorry, I ment: `@ManagedBean (name="DvdStreamSelectBean")`.

Comment: I've tried to use lower case convention (`dvdStreamSelectBean`) - no luck. Seems like a bug in JBoss Tools plugin. Where to report this?